# jQuery insertBefore and single quote issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing a `insertBefore` in jQuery

```
$.post('/blah', { blah : "some data" }, function(response) { 
   $(response).insertBefore($this); $this.val(''); }, "script"); }
```

On Rails side, `create.erb.js`

```
'<div style="background-color:yellow;"><%= show_content %></div>'
```

This code works just fine until the output contains a `'` which breaks the HTML rendering. Essentially the return string contains something like this

```
'<div ...>It's a beautiful day</div>'
```

I am on Rails 3.0.x and have tried various combinations of escaping unescaping on both Rails and Javascript and nothing works, any suggestion? I could change `'` to `"` but that just shifts the problem to another character that will break.

**EDIT**
Ok, this is way more complicated that I thought but I found a solution after many trials and errors

On Rails side, `create.erb.js`

```
'<div style="background-color:yellow;"><%= raw(show_content.gsub(/'/, "%27")) %></div>'
```

jQuery

```
$.post('/blah', { blah : "some data" }, function(response) { 
   $(unescape(response)).insertBefore($this); $this.val(''); }, "script"); }
```

Comment: You escaped only one symbol but there're another symbols and here's no guarantee that you won't encounter them

Comment: yeah I tested that but none of the other special character seems to have a problem, just the single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and errors, I found the solution, it's not as simple as I hope but it works, see edited question for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to put HTML before an element. It's move obvious to use:

```
$(element).before( YOUR HTML );
```

Or maybe a better solution should be:

```
$(element).html( YOUR HTML)
```

And put a span with a id to hold your HTML.

Comment: I seem to recall some problem with using `before` with a textbox

Answer (score 1):

Use a backslash to escape it like this

```
'<div ...>It\'s a beautiful day</div>'
```

**Edit:**

Maybe you should check out these links: [Let unescape_js handle escaped single quotes](https://github.com/snowyote/jquery-rails/commit/5c32a4745761038e5a02db71a3a80c5fa45e990b) or [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)

Comment: @Bob Are you sure there isnt something else wrong because I have looked around and this is the suggestion everyone is giving

Comment: @Bob You can even check out this link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_special_characters.asp

Comment: I just found a solution, check my edited question above. Believe you me, I have tried every which way of combination, problem appears to be Rails auto escaping output and jQuery / Javascript mangling it somehow.

Comment: @Bob I found a link about escaping single quotes in rails and jquery. Maybe it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use `html_escape` method or it's synonym `h()` from ERB::Util.